Android Webview Opens new Chrome sessions
I was trying to create a Google Auth login for a webview app.
It works as following

user Clicks on Login with Google button in app, default/Chrome browser will open showing all logged in Google account to login.

user selects account, continues, and using App:// link I am able to redirect user back to my app and also able to read the URL parameters passed.
package com.webviewtemplate.webviewtemplate
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.window.OnBackInvokedDispatcher
import com.webviewtemplate.webviewtemplate.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
class MainActivity : Activity() {
// URL of the web page to load
private val applicationUrl = "https://fieldops.testurl.com/app.html"
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var webView: WebView

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    webView = binding.webView

    // Handle the intent and extract query parameters if present
    val intent = intent
    val data = intent.data
    var targetUrl = applicationUrl

    if (data != null && data.scheme == "myapp") {
        // Extract the 'code' parameter from the incoming intent
        val code = data.getQueryParameter("code")
        if (!code.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            // Append the code to the application URL as a query parameter
            targetUrl = "$applicationUrl?code=$code"
        }
    }

    // Enable necessary WebView settings
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    // Handle back navigation for WebView
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        onBackInvokedDispatcher.registerOnBackInvokedCallback(
            OnBackInvokedDispatcher.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        ) {
            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack()
            } else {
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    // Load the target URL into the WebView
    webView.loadUrl(targetUrl)
}

}


so the Google Auth works fine, the issue is in webview app, the main domain/URL opens only on launch, after that whereever i click, it opens on Chrome.
Instead I want to open all the URLs inside the mail/give domain inside the webview app and all other in Chrome/default browser.
I tried many ways, but all of them works, but for external links it opens a different Chrome session in which I cant see any of my logged in Google account and the app:// links are not working - so even if I enter my Google credentials, it wont redirect back to webview app.
How can I properly use the default session of chrome by triggering from webview app ?
